# Neo4j cypher query slow performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried the example given [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-java.html) after some minor modifications - mainly I added a where clause without a match - for experimental purpose.

On my system (1.9.M04 - java 6u43 - ubuntu 12.04 - AMD phenom II -X6 1090T ) the simple query

With just 1 node in database (also embedded ) took  262 ms. Obviously something is going wrong. What could be the problem ?

Thanks

```
public void test()
    {
        GraphDatabaseService db = g = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("./neo4j1test" );

        long id;
        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        try
        {
            Node refNode = db.createNode();
            id = refNode.getId();
            refNode.setProperty( "name", "reference node" );
            tx.success();
        }
        finally
        {
            tx.finish();
        }


        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( "start n=node("+id+") where ( n.name = \"reference node\") return n.name" );
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        result = engine.execute( "start n=node("+id+") where ( n.name = \"reference node\") return n.name" );
        time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        System.out.println("Time taken : " + time + " ms.");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just the neo4j bootstrapping overhead, you should try to repeat the query more times, in that case I think the execution time should be significantly lower.

Comment: first try to warm up the caches. run this command few times: `start n=node(*) return count(n);start r=rel(*) return count(r)`. second, how do you measure the time? is it the time given by cypher output or simply the time before and after the specific line of code? in the second case the latency could be between your app and the server

Comment: Ok here is how it behaves - Already I measured the time of second query execution only (expecting the first execution would initialize the internal caching etc ..). But here it is different. it is the third  execution onward it takes significantly less time. I am not getting what is special about 3rd execution for the same query.   remigio thanks for the tip, ulkas, I am using it in embedded mode

Comment: At the 3rd time, your database caches are warm. Also, make sure you do  `ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );` only once, as it also is a reusable and one-time expensive operation.

Comment: I think it is the query parsing(converting it into some intermediate form - an ast perhaps) if it is not found in the cache- is where the time is spent .If this is correct -  1) Exposing a query builder where user can type random queries will face the above stated delay problem as queries are random and may not be in cache. 2). if so, first execution should parse the query and place it in  cache. then second execution should be faster. But here only from 3rd execution. I could be completely wrong. Peter please throw some light.I observed each different queries become faster from 3rd execution

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to index your name property (see [indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html)). After that, you could query like this:

```
START n=node:your_index_name("name:the_indexed_name") RETURN n;
```

Lookup up nodes via the index will be a lot faster than filtering via a WHERE clause.

Comment: yes I know that. the query is for experimental purpose only - to see how it behaves .

Comment: Hi @tstorms, I have similar problem with neo4j. I have created some node with index and connected it with relations. Now when I tried to get mutual count, It is performing very slow. My query took almost 2-3 seconds to fetch about 150 records from neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with Cypher querying technic. Poor performance caused by overhead of processing Cypher declarative query. I agree with you that overhead is impermissible huge.

We should use Core Java API to get full power of neo4j.

See this article: [Get the full neo4j power by using the Core Java API](http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/get-the-full-neo4j-power-by-using-the-core-java-api-for-traversing-your-graph-data-base-instead-of-cypher-query-language/)

And this: [Performance of Graph Query Languages: Comparison of Cypher, Gremlin and Native Access in Neo4j](http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2013-Genova/papers/workshops/a29-holzschuher.pdf)